# How to hide quickactions but still use them in macros

Tags: service-cloud-console, quickaction, macros

I am using the Service Cloud Console and want to use the Macro feature. I have a specific quickaction with a number of fields that can be changed, but to be able to use these in the macro actions, the quickactions has to be visible to the user.

This allows the user to still manually change some fields, perhaps incorrectly. I would like to prevent users from editing fields on this quickaction unless they are using a macro, but removing the action from their layout also breaks the macros.

Is there an option somewhere to set something like this up?